# Layered navigation with 3-tier product structure

Tags: layered-navigation

I have a custom 3-tier product structure where the associations are from grouped (GP) to configurable (CP) to simple products (SP). This is achieved using [this extension](http://instore.gorillagroup.com/magento-extensions/grouped-configurable-products). Standard associated table is used (i.e. `catalog_product_super_link`) for both GP-to-CP associations and CP-to-SP associations. Only GPs are visible on the frontend.

By default, the layered navigation shows the attributes of the parent and its immediate children, so it currently shows attributes of GPs and CPs only.

**What I'd like to do:**

I want layered navigation to include attributes of the simple products as well. I'm looking at `Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer` where a lot of the actions are happening, but I can't seem to find where it actually goes to the children products (in my case CPS) and grab their attributes.

At first, I thought instead of the product collection containing just the GP, I'll intercept it and append the GP's associated CPs as well, but it's more involved than I had imagined.

Any pointers?

I've looked at this if you were thinking about linking it: [Ignoring Child Product Attributes in Layered Navigation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5371/ignoring-child-product-attributes-in-layered-navigation)

EE 1.13

Comment: You'll need to clarify what you mean by *"associations... from grouped to configurable to simple products"*

Comment: Hey Ben, I've updated clarified my post.